# What exactly is supplied (供) in 供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from an article about The Bund 外滩 in Shanghai in the textbook 新实用汉语课本5, page 79 ([photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OltRa.jpg)):

> “情人墙”建在黄浦江边，全长约1700米。观光台的地面是彩色的，有32个半圆形的观景阳台，还有很多方灯、花坛、方亭、六角亭和绿化带，**供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景**。

I don't understand precisely what is being supplied (供) here.  Literally it's:

> ...supply [供] tourists [游人] rest [休息] and [并] appreciate [欣赏] Huangpu River banks [黄浦江两岸] scenery [美景].

It feels somewhat illogical to me; it doesn't seem possible to supply rest, nor scenery (nor "appreciation").  I asked a few AIs and they seem to think it's okay, but it seems we could also append words to the effect of 的机会 ("opportunities to rest and appreciate the scenery") or 的地方 ("places to rest and appreciate the scenery") and it'd be clearer.

**Question**: What exactly is supplied (供) in 供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景?

Answer (score 2):

Appending 的机会 would make it wrong. The structure is sth. 供 sb. do sth.

Here, it is 供游人休息 and 供游人欣赏美景, both 休息 and 欣赏 are verbs.《辞海》interprets 供 in 供人休息 as 使满足需要, so 游人休息 is a 需要, which is satisfied by the subject. But perhaps it is best translated to "can be used by tourists to rest".

As for the subject, I read it to be 观光台.

Answer (score 2):

"供" means "be provided for" here

> 方灯、花坛、方亭、六角亭和绿化带, 供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景(用)。

> Square lanterns, flower beds, square pavilions, hexagonal pavilions, and a green area are provided for tourists to rest and enjoy the Huangpu River bank scenery

The things being provided are square lanterns, flower beds, square pavilions, hexagonal pavilions, and a green area (for the tourists to use for sigh-seeing)

Actual, all of the above are parts of the 观光台 (observation deck), you can say "The observation deck is provided for the tourists to use for rest and enjoy the Huangpu River banks scenery

A shorter example:

多種顏色[**供**]客人選擇 Various colors [**for**] customers to choose from

The things being provided are choices of color

Answer (score 2):

供 means 提供某种条件使某件事可以发生 (similar to enable), which is better translated to "for":

Examples:

- 供游人休息: for tourists to rest
- 仅供参考: for reference only
- 我们准备了拖鞋供您使用: we prepared slippers for your use

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is supplied (供) in 供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景?

"供" means (something) is provided for

The objects that are provided include:

（1）**观光台**供游人休息并欣赏美景。

（2）观光台有**32个观景阳台**, 供游人休息并欣赏美景。

（3）**观光台**（32个观景阳台），还有**方灯、花坛、方亭、六角亭和绿化带**，（都）供游人休息并欣赏美景。

Answer (score -1):

Just a descriptive clause.

六角亭和绿化带，
hexagonal pavillions and green areas,
供游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景。
(which) provide tourists with a place to rest and appreciate the beautiful scenery on both banks of the Huangpu River.

Answer (score -2):

The complete sentence should be:

- 方灯、花坛、方亭、六角亭和绿化带, **(提)供**游人休息并欣赏黄浦江两岸的美景(用)。